# using jq to display pretty json and grep at the output to filter values

Tags: json, linux, curl, jq

On linux, i actually use jq associated with a curl command.
Something like this..

```
 curl <curl expression> | jq
```

but my pretty json at output got two many lines.
I'd like to filter rows, with something like this :

```
 curl <curl expression> | jq | grep myfilter
```

jq util do not accept to be grepped.
How can i do the work ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, sample data & example output please.

Comment: Use `jq`'s `select`

Comment: Could you describe your problem in more detail? It's not clear what you mean when you say that jq does not "accept to be grepped". Do you get some error? Or is the output unsatisfactory? If so, you should give a concrete example and explain what is a problem with it.

Comment: @Weeble my command is : curl <curl-expression> | jq | grep FR12454344. error message is ==> Error scanning file
"/run/snapd/lock/jq.lock". Access to the file has been denied

Comment: If you really want to use `grep`, try `jq .` instead of just `jq`.

Comment: You should edit your question to include that information, since it's necessary for anyone to answer. It is not normal for jq to break like this when output is piped into grep. It sounds like you have jq installed as a snap and something is broken about the installation. This may be relevant, I'm not sure: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/test-failures-with-cannot-create-lock-directory-run-snapd-lock/390

Comment: This works just fine for me: `$ curl -s 'https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq' | jq | grep name`

Comment: @peak it works fine with jq . instead of jq

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use grep, try `jq .` instead of just `jq`. Some older versions of jq in effect did the wrong thing under some circumstances when no filter was specified.